# Show $ny - y^n \leq n-1$ for $y \geq 0$ by induction

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

Show $ny - y^n \leq n-1$ for $y \geq 0$ by induction.

My attempt:

I can show this without induction by using lagrange multipliers, showing that the LHS has a maximum value of $n-1$, but I am struggling with the proof by induction.

It is easy to show for $n=1$ and $n=2$, but the case of $n = k+1$ given it is true for $n=k$ is more difficult. I tried to naively apply the inequality:

$$(k+1)y - y^{k+1} = ky + y - y^{k+1} \leq k-1 + y^k + y - y^{k+1}$$

So that all that remains to show is that $y^k + y - y^{k+1} \leq 1$. I think this is true so I'll try to prove it by splitting the claim into two parts: for $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $y > 1$:

For $0 \leq y \leq 1$: we know that $y + y^{n-1}(1-y) \leq 1$. Since $y \leq 1$ then the second term on the LHS is decreasing with the exponent so that: $y + y^{n}(1-y) \leq 1$ as desired

For $y > 1$: Taking the derivative with respect to $y$ we can see that $y^k + y - y^{k+1}$ is decreasing with $k$ for all $y \geq 1$. But is there some way to show this that does not require calculus?

I could use some feedback on my reasoning as well as simpler approaches to showing the claim.

Comment: Let $y=1+x.$ Then this is equivalent to Bernoulli’s inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: Ah that's great, I had tried to apply Bernoulli's too early on but hadnt considered this reparametrization. Thanks for the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$k-1 + y^k + y - y^{k+1} = k + (y-1) - y^k (y-1) = k + (y-1) (1-y^k) = k + (y-1) (1-y^k) \le k$$
$$(y-1) (1-y^k) \le 0$$
Now if $y<1$ then $y-1$ is negative while $1-y^k$ is positive, if $y>1$ it's the other way around, and if $y=1$ you have $0\le0$ which is trivially true.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the inequality as $$y^n\geq 1+n(y-1)$$ and we see that this is [Bernoulli’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

The traditional proof of Bernoulli is by induction. We can apply the same proof here, if we need an inductive proof.

From $n$ we get $n+1$ by multiplying both sides by $y.$

$$y^{n+1}\geq y+ny(y-1).$$

Then show the right side is $\geq 1+(n+1)(y-1).$